# How to manage syslog/kernel log rotation policy in k8s nodes

Tags: logging, kubernetes

I am using azure AKS for k8s deployment. Recently, I observed that the pods were getting evicted because of Node Disk Pressure. On checking the node filesystem usage, I found that the 90%  of nodefs was used up, of which 55% was occupied by syslog, kernel log, and messages.

One way I can think of handling this is by creating a daemonset that can manage the `/var/log/` directory and truncate the logs based on a certain policy, but not sure if this is a good practice.

Is there a better way to do this?

PS: the `/var/log/containers/*.log` is not an issue because docker-daemon.json has a rotation policy predefined by aks which works well for us.

Comment: Did you take a look https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#evicting-end-user-pods ? See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/ Check nodes' memory usage using command `kubectl top nodes` Did you take a look https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#evicting-end-user-pods ? Also can you provide your pod/deployment ( which are evicted ) config files.

Comment: @Malgorzata Actually I went through the docs you mentioned, and I believe the eviction was necessary because the node storage had reached 90% of which 55% of just syslog/kernel.log. Sorry if that was not clear, As mentioned above the /var/log/containers/*.log has less than 1mb of content, but since I am using AKS managed nodes, I do not have direct control over the syslog rotation policy, though from rsyslog config I do see that it is set to rotate daily, but that does not seem to work, I am ok with the eviction if nodefs limit is reached but what would be the best way to avoid such a scenario

Comment: Do you have resourceLimits set for pods ? Can you provide your pod/deployment ( which are evicted ) config files. Also find similar problem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/244101/syslogmessageskernlog-rollover-not-working-on-aks.html